# Install PhantomJS 2.0.0 on Red-Hat

Tags: build, openssl, phantomjs, redhat

**Description**

Operating System: RedHAT 6 x64

Phantomjs version: 2.0.0  ([phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/))

Steps to build: [document](http://phantomjs.org/build.html)

```
yum -y install gcc gcc-c++ make flex bison gperf ruby \
  openssl-devel freetype-devel fontconfig-devel libicu-devel sqlite-devel \
  libpng-devel libjpeg-devel
git clone git://github.com/ariya/phantomjs.git
cd phantomjs
git checkout 2.0
./build.sh
```

**Problem:**

We got an error when building source (may be reason is openssl):

> undefined reference to EC_KEY_free

Comment: We re-built openssl but it wasn't effective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Openssl default version in RedHat 6.4 is 1.0.0, You should update to newer version. I have installed successfully with openssl-1.0.1e-30.el6_6.7.x86_64

Hope that help

Comment: thanks, we have Open SSL 1.0.1g 7 Apr 2014 , i think with lower version we can install phantomjs 2.0 but as you know, many security problems when using lower version.